# Subclassing and overriding Django Class based views

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm building a website using django-all auth for it's authentication and social authentication functions. The forms that come bundled with the app are hardly great to look at and hence I decided to create my own views.

The problem is: How do I create them while ensuring that the backend of Django all auth is still available to me? I've dug into the source code and found that it uses class based views for rendering and performing CRUD operations.

I want to know if I can subclass those views in my own app/views.py and just change their template_name field to my own templates. Any advice would be most helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to just override a class and change the template_name, or you could just make your own template with the same name. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You can of course subclass the views, as long as you change your URLs to point to the overridden versions. However, there is no need to do this just to use your own templates; Django's template loader is specifically written with this use case in mind. Simply create your own directory inside your templates folder to match the one allauth is using, and create your own template files inside it; Django will find yours first and use them.

Comment: I didn't understand how exactly, could you provide a link or a code sample?

Comment: Thanks, I got to the docs and did it. If it was not for your hint I'd have been stuck.